# Problem with /joint_states: "New joint state is not newer than the previous state" warn

Tags: gazebo, moveit, joint-states

i'm using Gazebo and MoveIt with an Arduino Tinkerkit Braccio, when I launch the simulation I get a bunch of this warning messages

```
[ WARN] [1709550894.734646833]: New joint state for joint 'base_joint' is not newer than the previous state. Assuming your rosbag looped.
[ WARN] [1709550894.834698189]: New joint state for joint 'base_joint' is not newer than the previous state. Assuming your rosbag looped.
[ WARN] [1709550894.927419354]: New joint state for joint 'base_joint' is not newer than the previous state. Assuming your rosbag looped.
[ WARN] [1709550895.020475725]: New joint state for joint 'base_joint' is not newer than the previous state. Assuming your rosbag looped.
[ WARN] [1709550895.108109676]: New joint state for joint 'base_joint' is not newer than the previous state. Assuming your rosbag looped.
```

Tried to take a look to rqt_graph, as suggested [here](https://%5B%20WARN%5D%20%5B1709550894.734646833%5D:%20New%20joint%20state%20for%20joint%20%27base_joint%27%20is%20not%20newer%20than%20the%20previous%20state.%20Assuming%20your%20rosbag%20looped.%20%5B%20WARN%5D%20%5B1709550894.834698189%5D:%20New%20joint%20state%20for%20joint%20%27base_joint%27%20is%20not%20newer%20than%20the%20previous%20state.%20Assuming%20your%20rosbag%20looped.%20%5B%20WARN%5D%20%5B1709550894.927419354%5D:%20New%20joint%20state%20for%20joint%20%27base_joint%27%20is%20not%20newer%20than%20the%20previous%20state.%20Assuming%20your%20rosbag%20looped.%20%5B%20WARN%5D%20%5B1709550895.020475725%5D:%20New%20joint%20state%20for%20joint%20%27base_joint%27%20is%20not%20newer%20than%20the%20previous%20state.%20Assuming%20your%20rosbag%20looped.%20%5B%20WARN%5D%20%5B1709550895.108109676%5D:%20New%20joint%20state%20for%20joint%20%27base_joint%27%20is%20not%20newer%20than%20the%20previous%20state.%20Assuming%20your%20rosbag%20looped.) but everything seems ok, any idea? Thanks!

EDIT

this is my launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <arg name="connect_braccio" default="false" />
  <arg name="robot_name" default="kuka" />
  <arg name="use_ros_control" default="False" />
  <arg name="use_rviz" default="False" />
  <arg name="rd" default="robot_description" />

  <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>

    <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find braccio_moveit_gazebo)/worlds/test_ramp_bowl.world"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
<arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
<arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>

    <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
  <include file="$(find braccio_description)/launch/kr5.1_upload.launch">
 <arg name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_name)" />
     <arg name="use_ros_control" value="$(arg use_ros_control)" />
  </include>

  <!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
        args="-urdf -model $(arg robot_name) -param $(arg rd)"/>

  <include file="$(find braccio_moveit_gazebo)/launch/controller_utils.launch"/>

  <rosparam file="$(find braccio_moveit_gazebo)/config/arm_controller_kr5.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <node name="gripper_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn gripper_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  
  <!-- start moveit: -->
  <include file="$(find braccio_moveit_config)/launch/start_moveit_connected_with_gz.launch" >
<arg name="use_rviz" value="$(arg use_rviz)" />
    <arg name="robot_description" value="$(arg rd)" />
  </include>

  <include if="$(arg connect_braccio)" file="$(find braccio_moveit_gazebo)/launch/connect.launch">
  </include>
</launch>
```

these are joint_states values from /joint_states topic

```
header: 
  seq: 456
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 544000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 0.5906869275476527, 3.1415930411251933, 3.1068476078756504, 0.0166313446406825, 1.2692364706673596, 1.2480973823986874]
velocity: [0.0006761669248884312, 0.013516640100437948, -0.01870666121160319, 0.007239206272643424, 0.02740521304333446, -0.16606794002531394, 0.1623511295557024]
effort: [-0.024189117983818318, 0.264031071738128, -0.25667197277709275, -0.36656241739898365, 0.09008998631013286, -0.04713683746992126, 0.04607040711577365]
---
header: 
  seq: 2241
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 563000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251907, 1.2692364706673596, 0.5906869275476527, 1.2480973823986874, 3.1068476078756504, 0.0166313446406825]
velocity: [0.0006761669248761142, -0.018706661212007245, -0.16606794002438222, 0.013516640100699848, 0.16235112955472367, 0.007239206273243052, 0.027405213043380842]
effort: [-0.024189117983736207, -0.25667197278419823, -0.0471368374697807, 0.2640310717555505, 0.0460704071156298, -0.3665624174046385, 0.0900899863096297]
---
header: 
  seq: 2242
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 583000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251916, 1.2692364706673587, 0.5906869275476527, 1.2480973823986856, 3.106847607875652, 0.0166313446406825]
velocity: [0.0006761669249190447, -0.01870666121265499, -0.16606794002431502, 0.01351664010094274, 0.16235112955467743, 0.007239206273443379, 0.027405213043568702]
effort: [-0.024189117984062033, -0.2566719728090671, -0.04713683746988164, 0.26403107175539, 0.04607040711573759, -0.366562417405013, 0.09008998631744328]
---
header: 
  seq: 2243
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 603000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251907, 1.2692364706673587, 0.5906869275476518, 1.2480973823986865, 3.1068476078756504, 0.01663134464068161]
velocity: [0.0006761669249116388, -0.01870666121228952, -0.1660679400248413, 0.01351664010084086, 0.1623511295556375, 0.007239206273206772, 0.027405213043480394]
effort: [-0.02418911798396281, -0.2566719727841982, -0.04713683746987615, 0.26403107176385804, 0.046070407115889674, -0.36656241738438833, 0.09008998631842502]
---
header: 
  seq: 2244
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 623000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251916, 1.2692364706673596, 0.5906869275476527, 1.2480973823986856, 3.1068476078756504, 0.0166313446406825]
velocity: [0.0006761669249103043, -0.01870666121266088, -0.16606794002468891, 0.013516640101109974, 0.16235112955520864, 0.0072392062732727445, 0.027405213043496395]
effort: [-0.024189117983901432, -0.2566719728090672, -0.047136837469956755, 0.2640310717535823, 0.046070407115900755, -0.3665624174029495, 0.09008998631828186]
---
header: 
  seq: 457
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 631000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 0.5906869275476527, 3.1415930411251916, 3.1068476078756504, 0.0166313446406825, 1.2692364706673596, 1.2480973823986856]
velocity: [0.0006761669249103043, 0.013516640101109974, -0.01870666121266088, 0.0072392062732727445, 0.027405213043496395, -0.16606794002468891, 0.16235112955520864]
effort: [-0.024189117983901432, 0.2640310717535823, -0.2566719728090672, -0.3665624174029495, 0.09008998631828186, -0.047136837469956755, 0.046070407115900755]
---
header: 
  seq: 2245
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 643000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251924, 1.2692364706673596, 0.5906869275476518, 1.2480973823986865, 3.1068476078756504, 0.01663134464068161]
velocity: [0.0006761669249265444, -0.01870666121262283, -0.16606794002470485, 0.013516640101051627, 0.16235112955534542, 0.007239206273290939, 0.0274052130436664]
effort: [-0.02418911798400828, -0.2566719728019618, -0.047136837469953494, 0.264031071763262, 0.04607040711575993, -0.36656241738267675, 0.09008998632633693]
---
header: 
  seq: 2246
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 663000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251924, 1.2692364706673587, 0.5906869275476527, 1.2480973823986865, 3.1068476078756504, 0.01663134464068161]
velocity: [0.0006761669249336897, -0.018706661212266808, -0.16606794002465555, 0.0135166401008863, 0.16235112955539263, 0.007239206273212555, 0.027405213043564886]
effort: [-0.024189117975015904, -0.25667197280196175, -0.04713683746986424, 0.2640310717455032, 0.04607040711588683, -0.3665624174032233, 0.09008998632753244]
---
header: 
  seq: 2247
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 683000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.14159304112519, 1.2692364706673596, 0.5906869275476527, 1.2480973823986856, 3.1068476078756504, 0.01663134464068161]
velocity: [0.00067616692491732, -0.01870666121267165, -0.16606794002438985, 0.013516640101134823, 0.16235112955518807, 0.007239206273205641, 0.027405213043538296]
effort: [-0.024189117983923186, -0.2566719727877509, -0.04713683747002835, 0.26403107176093155, 0.04607040711594069, -0.3665624174045261, 0.09008998632770597]
---
header: 
  seq: 2248
  stamp: 
    secs: 67
    nsecs: 703000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
 - base_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.05968953157919277, 3.1415930411251916, 1.2692364706673605, 0.5906869275476527, 1.2480973823986874, 3.106847607875652, 0.0166313446406825]
velocity: [0.0006761669249221126, -0.01870666121264797, -0.16606794002445635, 0.01351664010103419, 0.1623511295553943, 0.007239206273396697, 0.027405213043586996]
effort: [-0.02418911798409593, -0.2566719728090672, -0.04713683746986612, 0.2640310717544351, 0.046070407115867275, -0.36656241740432316, 0.09008998631723197]
---
header: 
  seq: 7555
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 733000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580731508129, 3.141611544694432, 1.2741545817703406, 0.4045995847584587, 1.141255964798841, 3.117248701104959, 0.017537267931205136]
velocity: [-0.001152441118158128, 0.020313346882886905, -0.013745679055875698, -0.0028575291804206412, -0.10650548399317056, -0.00899354973469347, -0.026636223386835314]
effort: [-0.010352038349105358, 0.15020399643812332, 0.0, -0.09259095358718275, 0.010889627170402096, -0.40834408848393394, -0.48360984605273993]
---
header: 
  seq: 7556
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 753000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580168290745, 3.1416103954671843, 1.2744019489165979, 0.40460098323745, 1.141248463906937, 3.1172482333836324, 0.017537272995516773]
velocity: [-0.0011598933999740209, 0.018411134198293502, 0.35332183340238893, -0.0008051890879689563, -0.1136944509858311, -0.010784259119278819, -0.026623290751864304]
effort: [-0.010364709992192186, 0.14641770479115954, 0.0912658829392527, -0.09014715913940305, 0.011287526992379506, -0.42012606408276143, -0.4835522786808153]
---
header: 
  seq: 1518
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 757000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
position: [0.06508580168290745, 0.40460098323745, 3.1416103954671843, 3.1172482333836324, 0.017537272995516773, 1.2744019489165979, 1.141248463906937]
velocity: [-0.0011598933999740209, -0.0008051890879689563, 0.018411134198293502, -0.010784259119278819, -0.026623290751864304, 0.35332183340238893, -0.1136944509858311]
effort: [-0.010364709992192186, -0.09014715913940305, 0.14641770479115954, -0.42012606408276143, -0.4835522786808153, 0.0912658829392527, 0.011287526992379506]
---
header: 
  seq: 7557
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 773000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580167065592, 3.141610389450701, 1.2743782971214532, 0.4046007520653463, 1.1412469327777712, 3.117248346937531, 0.017537273026419165]
velocity: [-0.0011602226601565924, 0.018328789506495087, 0.36608511492664714, -0.0004432289907347342, -0.11321562381935893, -0.01112225548746233, -0.02662220681559086]
effort: [-0.010365131426930914, 0.14617174490362886, 0.09397022013775011, -0.0874145744409037, 0.011459314621632528, -0.42157932225202055, -0.48355176171758135]
---
header: 
  seq: 7558
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 793000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580731508218, 3.141611544694431, 1.2741545817703406, 0.4045995847584587, 1.1412559647988418, 3.117248701104959, 0.017537267931204248]
velocity: [-0.001152441118121179, 0.02031334688314374, -0.013745679055875667, -0.002857529180388488, -0.10650548399270061, -0.008993549734997426, -0.026636223387004547]
effort: [-0.010352038340489872, 0.15020399644574994, 0.0, -0.09259095358830183, 0.01088962717048278, -0.4083440884822836, -0.48360984606074703]
---
header: 
  seq: 7559
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 813000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580168290834, 3.1416103954671843, 1.2744019489165979, 0.4046009832374491, 1.1412484639069378, 3.1172482333836324, 0.01753727299551766]
velocity: [-0.0011598934000255977, 0.018411134197881204, 0.35332183340222095, -0.0008051890879492967, -0.11369445098588439, -0.01078425911883215, -0.026623290752156886]
effort: [-0.010364710000722116, 0.14641770478701177, 0.09126588293916733, -0.09014715914902027, 0.011287526992275242, -0.4201260640874375, -0.48355227868747463]
---
header: 
  seq: 7560
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 833000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580167065592, 3.141610389450701, 1.2743782971214532, 0.4046007520653463, 1.1412469327777712, 3.117248346937531, 0.017537273026419165]
velocity: [-0.001160222660183161, 0.01832878950656531, 0.36608511492697, -0.00044322899075968647, -0.11321562381947721, -0.011122255487421955, -0.02662220681573848]
effort: [-0.010365131426666587, 0.14617174490267726, 0.0939702201378201, -0.08741457444051631, 0.011459314621647348, -0.4215793222519799, -0.48355176171594294]
---
header: 
  seq: 7561
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 853000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580731508307, 3.141611544694431, 1.2741545817703424, 0.4045995847584587, 1.141255964798841, 3.117248701104959, 0.017537267931205136]
velocity: [-0.0011524411180547913, 0.020313346883206733, -0.01374567905552037, -0.002857529180504196, -0.10650548399309703, -0.00899354973491225, -0.026636223386993604]
effort: [-0.010352038350159572, 0.15020399644492669, 0.0, -0.09259095358696023, 0.010889627170396451, -0.40834408848230097, -0.48360984605100793]
---
header: 
  seq: 1519
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 857000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
position: [0.06508580731508307, 0.4045995847584587, 3.141611544694431, 3.117248701104959, 0.017537267931205136, 1.2741545817703424, 1.141255964798841]
velocity: [-0.0011524411180547913, -0.002857529180504196, 0.020313346883206733, -0.00899354973491225, -0.026636223386993604, -0.01374567905552037, -0.10650548399309703]
effort: [-0.010352038350159572, -0.09259095358696023, 0.15020399644492669, -0.40834408848230097, -0.48360984605100793, 0.0, 0.010889627170396451]
---
header: 
  seq: 7562
  stamp: 
    secs: 173
    nsecs: 873000000
  frame_id: ''
name: 
  - base_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - gripper_joint
  - shoulder_joint
  - sub_gripper_joint
  - wrist_pitch_joint
  - wrist_roll_joint
position: [0.06508580168290834, 3.1416103954671852, 1.2744019489165979, 0.4046009832374482, 1.1412484639069378, 3.1172482333836307, 0.017537272995515885]
velocity: [-0.0011598934001167639, 0.018411134198219534, 0.35332183340241247, -0.0008051890880492376, -0.11369445098624495, -0.01078425911903289, -0.02662329075221339]
effort: [-0.010364709999830489, 0.1464177047812094, 0.09126588293917763, -0.09014715913754787, 0.011287526992292816, -0.42012606408400216, -0.483552278686847]
---

---
```

I can see two things:

- there are two sets of headers: one with a lower seq number, which is published more rarely, and one with a higher seq number, which is published more often
- the base_joint position value is always the same  between the lower-seq and immediately preceding higher-seq and this generates the warn

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* caesar753. How are you publishing joint states for your base joint? What does your launch file look like? I would guess you have `/use_sim_time` set but aren't publishing a /clock message, so the message stamps are coming across as all at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!/clock message is published but you were right: in my .launch file the arg use_sim_time was set to false,now I set it to true and the warnings are far fewer but are still present,what should I look at?

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, taking guesses at things that could be wrong without more information to go on. Are the warnings you're seeing still the same warnings? I asked before and didn't get an answer - how are you publishing the base_joint value? It could also be something like you're not populating the header correctly (not updating the stamp or incrementing the sequence, etc.).

Comment: The warnings are the same; I edited the original post adding the .launch file
I don't know how to check how the base_joint value are published or where to look at.

Comment: added also /joint_states topic messages

Answer (score 0):

As you point out in your comment, you have two different nodes publishing your joint state message. When I look at your launch file, I see:

```
<rosparam file="$(find braccio_moveit_gazebo)/config/arm_controller_kr5.yaml" command="load"/>
<node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
<node name="gripper_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn gripper_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

So I'm expecting that there are two nodes publishing joint state messages (because of the independently-incrementing sequence values) and I see two nodes in your launch file.

I can see that you have `<arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>` and can also verify that your header stamps aren't [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

If I divide the header stamp by the sequence count then it looks like you've got one publisher firing at approximately (2241/67.563) = 33.17 Hz and another firing at approximately (456/67.544) = 6.75 Hz. I don't know if these numbers ring any bells for you or not.

My guess is that you've got the arm_controller and gripper_controller both publishing the full joint vector:

```
 - base_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
 - gripper_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
```

when you should instead have the arm controller publishing arm joint states:

```
 - base_joint
 - shoulder_joint
 - elbow_joint
 - wrist_pitch_joint
 - wrist_roll_joint
```

and the gripper controller publishing gripper joint states

```
 - gripper_joint
 - sub_gripper_joint
```

Looking more at your messages, the base_joint values are the same between both messages but the other angles are totally different. Since you've got different arm angles set on both controllers it's not clear to me which one is in control of which joints, but this is something where again you either need to have one controller or the other in charge of the entire arm, or you have one controller responsible for one set of joints and another controller responsible for the rest.

Comment: thanks for your help! but now: where should I look at  to solve the problem on the controllers? I tried to separate arm rosparam from gripper rosparam (created 2 .yaml files) but didn't work...

Comment: @caesar753 - It would be an issue inside the controllers, wherever you're publishing the joint states.